# Showing equality of primitive roots with quadratic non-residues.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Suppose that $p$ and $q = 2p + 1$ are both odd primes. Show that the $p − 1$
>   primitive roots of $q$ are precisely the quadratic non-residues of $q$, other than
>   the quadratic non-residue $2p$ of $q$.

I think I probably need to use the fact that $q$ is congruent to $3 \rm\, mod\, 4$, but I've been fiddling around with definitions and can't quite seem to get anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are possibly familiar with the result that says that if $n$ has a primitive root, then $n$ has $\varphi(\varphi(n))$ primitive roots.

In the case $q=2p+1$, the number of primitive roots of $q$ is therefore $\varphi(2p)$, which is $p-1$. But $p-1=\frac{q-1}{2}-1$. Since there are $\frac{q-1}{2}$ quadratic non-residues of $q$, and every primitive root is a non-residue, it follows that all but one of the non-residues is a primitive root.

Since $q$ is of the form $4k+3$, we know that $-1$ is a non-residue. But $-1$ is not a primitive root of $q$, since $q\gt 3$. So $-1$ is the only non-residue which is not a primitive root.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: The multiplicative group of non-zero residues mod $q$ is cyclic and has order $2p$. The possible orders of elements are $1,2,p,2p$ since $p$ is prime [this is where $p$ being prime comes in]. You need to work out which elements have which order, which is simply an analysis of the cyclic group.