# Let $p$ and $q=2p+1$ be two odd primes. Why is $2p$ a quadratic non-residue of $q$?

Tags: number-theory

I was checking this question [Showing equality of primitive roots with quadratic non-residues.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/800321/showing-equality-of-primitive-roots-with-quadratic-non-residues) and it is said that if $p$ and $q=2p+1$ are two odd primes, then $2p$ a quadratic non-residue of $q$. But I can't see why. I tried to suppose that there is an $x$ such that $x^2 \equiv 2p \equiv q-1 \equiv -1$ (mod q), but this does not seem to lead to a conclusion. Can someone help me?

Comment: $2p+1$ is always $\equiv 3\bmod 4$ for $p$ odd

Answer (score 3):

As stated in the comments, we have $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ since $q = 2p + 1$ and $p$ is an odd number. [Euler's criterion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_criterion) implies that $-1$ is a quadratic residue modulo an odd prime $p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$. Therefore, $2p \equiv -1 \pmod q$ has to be a quadratic nonresidue.